# stream.addTrack working in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webrtc, web-audio-api, mediastream

I'm having an issue with a project i'm working on for my brother's company and wanted to see if anybody had any ideas on how to fix it.

The company puts on virtual conferences for corporate events, nonprofits, etc. and its common with these things for people to need to pre-record their presentations with a powerpoint slideshow. For non-tech savvy clients (which is most of their clients), the only way to make this happen is to hire a contractor to work with with the client 1 on 1 to get their video recorded. My goal is to make a site where clients can easily record the video and slideshow themself, which would reduce their costs significantly.

Its still very much a work in progress, but what i have so far is live here: https://ezav-redesign-hf4d3.ondigitalocean.app/

The issue is, while the recording function works really well on Firefox, on Chrome it always ends up with no audio. You can see the full source code at the live site, but here is what I think should be the relevant part:

```
const video = document.createElement("video");
video.muted = true;
video.srcObject = stream;
video.play();
function update() {
ctx.drawImage(video, 300, 0, 720, 720, 1547, 297, 357, 355);
ctx.drawImage(
presentationCanvas,
0,
0,
presentationCanvas.width,
presentationCanvas.height,
20,
125,
presentationCanvas.width * 0.754,
presentationCanvas.height * 0.745
);
requestAnimationFrame(update); // wait for the browser to be ready to present another animation fram.
}
video.addEventListener("loadeddata", function () {
update(); //Start rendering
});
/* RECORDING */
const recStream = canvas.captureStream(30);
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
// create a stream from our AudioContext
var dest = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
audioStream = dest.stream;
// connect our video element's output to the stream
var sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video);
sourceNode.connect(dest);
recStream.addTrack(audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
```

I've spent most of the weekend googling and tinkering trying to fix this and have tested it on 3 different machines but i can't seem to get anywhere. Im not sure how to pinpoint exactly where its going wrong as the console isnt diplaying any errors. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug/limitation in Chrome, where they don't pass the audio stream of muted MediaElements to the graph at all anymore.

Luckily in your case it seems you absolutely don't need to go through the MediaElement since you have access to the raw MediaStream. So all you have to do is to get rid of the AudioContext part entirely and just do

```
stream.getAudioTracks().forEach( (track) => recStream.addTrack( track ) );
```